# Flutter : " type 'Teams' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast " error comes from request

Tags: flutter, request, provider

I have problem with send request in Flutter ,I have this model :

```
import 'dart:convert';
List<Teams> teamsFromJson(String str) =>
    List<Teams>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Teams.fromJson(x)));
String teamsToJson(List<Teams> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));
class Teams {
  Teams({
    this.club,
    this.price,
    this.surename,
    this.id,
    this.league,
  });
  final club;
  final price;
  final surename;
  final id;
  final league;
  factory Teams.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Teams(
        club: json["club"],
        price: json["price"],
        surename: json["surename"],
        id: json["id"],
        league: json["league"],
      );
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "club": club,
        "price": price,
        "surename": surename,
        "id": id,
        "league": league,
      };
}
```

I add initial values and update them in provider :

```
List<Teams> get teams => _teams;
List<Teams> _teams = [
    Teams(club: "", price: 0, surename: "", id: "", league: ""),
    Teams(club: "", price: 0, surename: "", id: "", league: ""),]
addToTeam(data, index) {
teams[index]=Team(club: data.club,
            price: data.price,
            surename: data.surname,
            id: data.id,
            league: data.leagueName);
}
```

and it works fine ,now I want to send the list teams as a request ,I add button and create method like this :

```
onPressed: () {
       ApiService().saveTeam(teamsProvider.teams);
      }
```

on ApiService I have this request :

```
class ApiService {
    var url = 'http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/v1';

  Future saveTeam(data) async {
    var newurl = Uri.parse(url + '/send_test');
    try {
      var response = await http.post(newurl, body: data);
      var result = jsonDecode(response.body);
      print(result);
    } catch (e) {
      print('error : $e');
    }
  }
}
```

the api request is just return the request in laravel :

```
public function send_test(Request $request)
    {
        return $request;
    }
```

as a result I get this error mesage : `type 'Teams' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast`
How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you post the full error stack trace?

Comment: @JaffaKetchup How can I do that?

Comment: Copy the large block of text that comes in the console after the error.

Comment: @JaffaKetchup I just get this : `I/flutter (17440): error : type 'Teams' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast`

Comment: So there's no line number? On any of the errors?

Comment: @JaffaKetchup no line number is found

Comment: You may need to do jsonEncode to your http.post body and please add types to your fields it would be so much easier to spot the mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by myself ,I converted the Team list to Sting and decoded it with json:

```
class ApiService {
  var url = 'http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/v1';

  Future saveTeam(List<Teams> data) async {
    var list = [];
    data.map((e) {
      list.add({
        "club": e.club,
        "price": e.price,
        "surename": e.surename,
        "id": e.id,
        "league": e.league
      });
    }).toList();
    try {
      var newurl = Uri.parse(url + '/send_test');
      var response = await http.post(newurl, body: jsonEncode(list));
      var result = jsonDecode(response.body);
      print(result);
    } catch (e) {
      print('error : $e');
    }
  }
}
```

then in api in laaravel/lumen received the json and decoded it again :

```
public function send_test(Request $request)
    {
        $result = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
        return $result;
    }
```